# Overloading Bitwise Operators to Work with Booleans in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class that I want to be able to do bitwise operations on in some cases.

```
class Measurement(object):
    def __init__(self, value = None, category = None, measure = None):
        self.value = value
        self.category = category
        self.measure = measure    

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.value.__nonzero__()

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.__nonzero__() | other

a = False
b = Measurement(True)
```

At this point `c = b | a` works, but `c = a | b` gives a type error. How do I get it to work both ways?

Also, is there a more elegant way to do this; for example, I had hoped that by just defining `__nonzero__`, I might get the right behaviour, but that's not the case.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Aha, this reminds me of a similar question I saw solved. It was about implementing a multiplication operation for a custom Vector class, and the solution was to override `__rmul__` (and make it call `__mul__` with the arguments switched). I wonder if there's a similar solution for this.

Comment: @Tagc yes. Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: This is the way it's suppose to be done. Explicit is better than implicit and all that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By also defining `__ror__`, as shown below, I get the right behaviour. The second part of the question still stands, however. Is there a more elegant way?

```
def __ror__(self, other):
    return self.__or__(other)
```

Comment: `__ror__`...I knew it.

Comment: No there isn't a better way.  You could potentially define `self.__ror__ = self.__or__`, but I think that would just be more confusing